# Incorrect result for integral of series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here's an integral that comes up in calculating the number of [domino tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling) of the plane:

```
Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]
(* 4 Catalan *)
```

And here is the same result with a trivial addition:

```
Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2] + x, {k, 0, π}]
(* 4 Catalan + π x *)
```

But if I change the integrand into a series, the result is different:

```
Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2] + x + O[x]^2, {k, 0, π}]
(* 4 Catalan + π (x + Log[2]) *)
```

Note the additional term independent of `x`. Surely this is a bug?

---

I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly in Mathematica 12, you get the wrong answer for your  original integral

```
Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]

(* 4 Catalan + π Log[2] *)

% // N
(* 5.84145 *)
```

We can verify this is incorrect numerically

```
NIntegrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]
(* 3.66386 *)
```

and that this is the same result as you obtained symbollically

```
4 Catalan // N
(* 3.66386 *)
```

For reference

```
$Version
(* "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

Following @Alx suggestion, I've found that the result depends on how the integral is formatted.  See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: With v12 on a Mac I get `4 Catalan`. What OS are you using?

Comment: @BobHanlon Updated answer with version information.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer actually, but more interesting observation (in addition to answer by @mikado). Fresh session, Mathematica 12, Windows 10:

[image]

So, the result depends on form of expression input: Input or Standard.

Comment: With v12 on a Mac I get `4 Catalan` with InputForm. What OS are you using?

Comment: Amazing things happen.

Comment: Updated OS information (Windows 10).