# Why should the format of an integral affect the result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, front-end

This has been reported to Wolfram and confirmed as a bug in Mathematica V12

---

This follows on from [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206930/incorrect-result-for-integral-of-series/206973?noredirect=1#comment532063_206973)

I get a different answer for the same integral input in  different ways e.g.

```
Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]
(* 4 Catalan + π Log[2] *)

\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(π\)]\(Log[\((Sin[
       k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])\)^2] \[DifferentialD]k\)\)
(* 4 Catalan *)
```

Numerical integration confirms that the second result is correct.

See the screenshot for a clearer view of what I did

[image]

As a further point of evidence, I get the correct answer if I wrap it in `Hold`, and then release it:

```
ReleaseHold[
 Hold[Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]]]
(* 4 Catalan *)
```

Comment: On `12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)` the result is `4 Catalan` for both.

Comment: On `10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)` the result is `4 Catalan` for both.

Comment: @mikado, I found another amazing behavior. If you change the order of inputs: In[3] and next In[1], then both results are correct. So, probably the correct result is with integral sign (your In[3]) and then MMA caches this somehow and uses with `Integrate[...]` (your In[1]) and gives right answer. MMA 12, Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format appears to be a distraction.  I get a different answer on the second time I evaluate the integral.

```
Quit[]

Hold[
 Integrate[Log[(Sin[k] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[k]^2])^2], {k, 0, π}]]

ReleaseHold[%]
(* 4 Catalan + π Log[2] *)

ReleaseHold[%%]
(* 4 Catalan *)

$Version
(* "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```